# Proxy to restrict access to certain websites

Tags: ubuntu, proxy, webfilter

I'm looking for a solution that allows our office server to function as a proxy that blocks access to certain websites for certain LAN ip's.

The solution i'm looking for has to meet these requirements:

- run on ubuntu server
- restrict access to certain websites based on a LAN ip (eg: shut out xxx.com for 192.168.1.152)
- restrict access to a website based on the website url (eg: shut out *.facebook.com)
- easily configurable (preferably through a web interface, our office manager should be able to operate it thus no commandline fu if possible)
- preferably opensource

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Does want you want, Open source, Easy to use - pick two...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.untangle.com/

Should fit your needs.

Comment: Thanks, although not open source the GUI is the clear winner here over squid. I don't want to imagine our manager to work in webmin and configure squid, untangle seems to solve most of that.

Answer (score 3):

[SQUID](http://www.squid-cache.org/) can do all that for you, except the web interface configuration, but for that you can try the Webmin plugin for Squid.

Answer (score 0):

To get the flexibility you are looking for in filtering I'd add SquidGuard to the list. Although it doesn't have a web GUI for configuration, it will let you define block lists by defined ranges of users and/or IP's on your LAN, and even by hour of day. Additionally both Squid and SquidGuard support LDAP so they can be integrated with Active Directory if you have it, to allow some ease of management. You could make some groups in your directory and then have someone else just modify user group membership that way.

I hear good things about Dan's Guardian but I've never actually used it. It's basically several packages bundled up with Squid and may have a web interface, but don't quote me on that.

You have plenty of choices here: http://www.squid-cache.org/Misc/related-software.dyn

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that you could do all of this (except you wouldn't need to run it locally - i.e. the Ubuntu/open source requirements go away) by switching from your ISP's DNS servers to OpenDNS.